# Set for ruby deploy public key path with homepath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To solve the connection problems in capistrano with the public key i add to deploy.rb

```
set :ssh_options, {
  auth_methods: ["publickey"],
  keys: ['c:/users/test/.ssh/id_rsa']
}
```

this works, but i want to make this path with the homepath instead of `c:/users/test`. I try to add `%USERHOME%` but so he cant find the key.

How can i say to ruby to use there the homepath of the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this, on OS:

`export KEY_PATH=${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa`

On ruby code:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  auth_methods: ["publickey"],
  keys: ENV['KEY_PATH']
}
```